# erro Migrations c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework, migrations

Criei um Controller de Movimentação de finanças, porém, quando clico no menu para me listar retorna o erro:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Movimentacaos'.

Por que ficou esse nome? Era para estar `Movimentacoes`.

PS: Já adicionei em meu contexto para desabilitar a pluralização com o código       `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`, porém continua ocorrendo o mesmo erro.

Comment: Pode postar o seu arquivo migration.cs aqui?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Por que ficou esse nome? Era para estar Movimentacoes

Isso acontece porque `dbo` é *schema* padrão do SQL Server. Você pode alterar isso usando o atributo `Table` na sua classe.

Ex.:

```
[Table("test.Movimentacoes")]
public class Movimentacao { ... }
```

O principal motivo para ocorrer este erro (não há como ter certeza sem maiores detalhes na pergunta) é que esta tabela não existe no banco de dados (aparentemente você está usando DatabaseFirst).